# Compute the borders and overlap of two HistoricalCountry entities?

Tags: geographics, entity

For CountryData, we can take the property "BorderingCountries", providing us with a notion of whether two countries border each other.

But for two HistoricalCountry entities, where we only have access to a Polygon, the notion of overlap and bordering becomes trickier to compute. The intersection of their Polygons might provide an overlap notion, but is it possible to additionally detect whether two Geo Polygons are simply next to each other?

Ideally I'd like to find their intersection or common border as a Geo-geometrical object.

Comment: You should be able to use `GeoDistance[..., DistanceFunction -> "Boundary"]` to do this - it should return zero for polygons that overlap or are very close (bordering)